# Логика работы роутинга Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет!

Начал изучать Laravel и столкнулся с не пониманием логики работы роутинга данного фреймворка.

**Что я хочу реализовать:**

1. Небольшую cms для вывода статей.
2. Через админку можно будет написать статью и создать уникальный `url` адрес этой статьи + при необходимости выбрать родительскую статью, чтобы получить адрес например `site.ru/page1/page2/`.

**Вопросы:**

3. Мне сказали, что `url` нужно обрабатывать в самом роутере, а не в контроллере, это верно?
4. Если его нужно обрабатывать в роутере, то написал такой роутер: `Route::get('/{slug}', ['uses' => 'FrontController@index'])->where(['slug' => '[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9/_-]+']);`.
5. В контроллере `FrontController > index` выполнил `return $slug`.
6. Заходим на страницу `site.ru/page1/page2/` и получаем текст `page1/page2`, так и должно быть?

Ну и заключительный вопрос, как грамотно писать роутер исходя из моей задачи?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Да, роуты обрабатываются в файле с роутами. Единственное, это проверка на наличие статьи со ссылкой /slug в бд, т.е. метод контроллера принимает параметр `$slug`, далее можно сделать `Article::where('slug', '=', $slug)->firstOrFail();`. В таком случае, сервер выдаст 404 ошибку, если статью он не найдет. О методе `firstOrFail()`и т.д. читай в описании Eloquent, там очень много интересного.
2. Да, все правильно, обрабатывай все через `Route::*method*(*params*)->where()`
3. Да, все правильно, поскольку ты в регулярке не убрал символ `/`. Исключи его и тогда этот запрос выдаст ошибку 404. Если же в `slug` может быть слэш, то тогда оставляй параметр таким.

Что касается правильного роутинга - нужно больше инфы, но все вроде бы просто. Сделать 2 группы - админка и пользовательская часть. В группе с админкой создать middleware admin, где будешь через `Auth` проверять, админ ли данный пользователь. В пользовательской части - маршрут для статьи, который ты выше уже написал, а также маршрут корня - `Route::get('/', *params*)`.

Comment: Если не возражаете еще пару вопросов:  
1. Допустим, мы приняли 'url - page1/page2/' `$slug` в контроллере, мы должны регуляркой его разобрать на `page1` и `page2`?
2. Как только мы его разобрали, получаем по `url` адресу `page2` содержимое этой страницы из БД?

Comment: Немного не понял. Если мы приняли url page1/page2, то лучше это в роутах делать -  `Route::get('{slug1}/{slug2}')`. Если же сам $slug может состоять из такого адреса, то можно делать это в контроллере через `$slug = explode( '/', $slug);`, это уже твой выбор, зависит все от задачи.

Comment: огромный поклон в 360 градусов! =)